# android unpublished app getting downloads

Tags: google-play

I lost the key for my google play app so I unpublished it and published a new one with a new package name.

It's been like 2 months since I unpublished it and during all the time I'm still getting downloads and ratings on the unpublished app. However if you searched on Google Play about it or went to the developer page, you wouldn't find it. I don't even know how people download it.
Here's the link for the unpublished app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.triple.nilesat

Comment: Did you get resolution to this? I notice your app is no longer at that URL. I am having a similar problem with an unpublished version of my app, I am still seeing downloads. After extensive research I've found if someone gets hold of that old APK file it can be installed, or if they previously downloaded it (even if deleted) they can install again. Check this thread out for similar info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/Xb2SllQUyJE/oUZf6Yfwg_YJ